# How to use debounceTime but still trigger the function after certain time?

Tags: angular, signalr, rxjs

TLDR;
I would like to use debounceTime to execute the function only if 300 milliseconds have passed without it being called. In the meanwhile, I also want to be able to trigger the function every 1 minutes If the process takes a long time. Otherwise, the function will only be triggered at the end of the process.

---

Basically, our system has a long process that will fire a lot of SignalR update to the client. When I received the server command on the client, I will make 2 additional HTTP requests back to server to get some information. So that It will hit the server back as long as the server sending me update.

> I am using `debounceTime` to prevent sending too many requests back to the
>   server If the time between two commands is within 300ms. But there is one
>   use case where the server constantly sending the update to the client in,
>   e.g 1 hour. Meaning the client will trigger the getItemCount at 1h and
>   300ms.

```
export class LeftNavigationComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    typeACount: number = 0;
    typeBCount: number = 0;    

    constructor(
        private itemService: service.ItemService,        
        private signalR: service.SignalRService) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.subscriptions = [            
            this.signalR.itemCreated.debounceTime(300).subscribe(item => this.onUpdatingData())]
    }

    onUpdatingData() {
        Promise.all([
            this.itemService.getItemCount(APP_SETTING.TYPE_A),
            this.itemService.getItemCount(APP_SETTING.TYPE_B)])
            .then(response => this.gettingCountDone(response))
    }

    gettingCountDone(response) {
        this.typeACount = <any>response[0];
        this.typeBCount = <any>response[1];        
    }
}
```

I still want to `debounceTime` to prevent sending too many requests to the server. But it should be smart enough to be automatically triggered every e.g 1 minutes after receiving the first updated. Has anyone had the use case before?

Comment: Could you clarify the _ to be automatically triggered every e.g 1 minutes after receiving the **first updated**_ -- what's "first updated". It would also help a lot understanding your problem if you showed a sketch of the desired behavior in a form of a marble diagram. Btw, it's a nice riddle to work on!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pavel answer is close, but If I have understood well the question, you want this:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    const debounced = this.signalR.itemCreated.debounceTime(300).share();
    this.subscriptions = [         
        debounced.subscribe(() => this.onUpdatingData()),
        debounced.switchMap(() => Observable.interval(60000).takeUntil(this.signalR.itemCreated)).subscribe(() => this.onUpdatingData())
    ]
}
```

This code will do the following, when the time between items created are major than 300ms onUpdatingData() will be called. After that Every time debounced emits a value, a throttleTime observable of 1 minit is created. Meaning that, if debounced doesn't emit for a minut since the last emision, onUpdatingData() will be executed, and so one.

And improvement would be to merge the observables, because they are from the same type and the execute the same function, for example like this:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    const debounced = this.signalR.itemCreated.debounceTime(300).share();
    const merged = debounced.switchMap(() => Observable.interval(60000).takeUntil(this.signalR.itemCreated))
    this.subscriptions = [         
      merged.subscribe(() => this.onUpdatingData())
   ]
}
```

I posted a fiddle showing the working solution. In this fiddle, the event mousedown simulates the stream this.signalR.itemCreated.

https://jsfiddle.net/llpujol/e6b6o655/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`throttleTime`](http://rxmarbles.com/#throttleTime)`(60000)` instead of or in parallel with `debounceTime`. To check this behavior move all balls to the beginning and you will see the result
[image]

In your case you can for example do the following:

```ts
ngOnInit(): void {
        this.subscriptions = [            
            this.signalR.itemCreated.debounceTime(300).subscribe(item => this.onUpdatingData()),
            this.signalR.itemCreated.throttleTime(60000).subscribe(item => this.onUpdatingData())
        ]
    }
```

So method won't be called too often and also once per minute (or less if there is no events).

It is also possible to write your own implementation and combine `debounceTime` with `throttleTime` but I'm not experienced enough too provide such example...

Comment: A complete example (with code) would be highly appreciated. I am trying to solve the OP's problem and am not very successful so far.

Comment: Thanks for your example. But is this gonna be the same If I do debounceTime(300).throttleTime(6000)?

Comment: No - in case of train it would first wait 300 ms then take the last event and emit it to the next car which is going to pass one and then throw away all others for 6 seconds so you won't be able to emit events more often than once per 6 sec.

Comment: I was going to write 1 minute instead of 6 seconds in my prev comment - this is typo

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take on it. The code is way way less elegant than one written by Pavel.

You can try it out in the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/4BpbXGkOeVS8y3vXwIsF?p=preview) I prepared. (You'll need to open browser console to see the generated output stream). You may also want to play with the `normalEventDebounceTime` and `forcedInterval` key configuration parameters, and/or with the event timing in `sourceObservable`.

The idea is to `merge` two streams (`sourceObervable` and `reschedulingObservable`) into one which will be triggered by either of the inputs. Whenever the merged observable emits an event, we call `reschedulingSubject.next()` thus delaying `reschedulingObservable` by `1000ms` (because it's constructed with `debounceTime` applied to `Subject`).

The `sourceObservable` is supposed to be truly independent, i.e. produced by user input, or -- in your case -- by SignalR as I understand.

---

```
const normalEventDebounceTime = 450;
const forcedInterval = 1000;

const sourceObservable = Rx.Observable.create(observer => {
  setTimeout(() => observer.next('event-0'), 0);
  setTimeout(() => observer.next('event-1'), 1000);
  setTimeout(() => observer.next('event-2'), 1100);
  setTimeout(() => observer.next('event-3'), 1500);
  setTimeout(() => observer.next('event-4'), 2000);
  setTimeout(() => observer.next('event-5'), 5000);
  setTimeout(() => observer.next('event-6'), 8000);
  setTimeout(() => observer.complete(), 9000);
});

const reschedulingSubject = new Rx.Subject();

const reschedulingObservable = reschedulingSubject.asObservable().debounceTime(forcedInterval);

const debouncedSourceObservable = sourceObservable.debounceTime(normalEventDebounceTime);

let keepWatching = true;

sourceObservable.subscribe(
  event => {},
  error => {},
  () => {
    keepWatching = false;
    console.info('Source observable is complete. Stop watching please');
  }
);

Rx.Observable
  .merge(debouncedSourceObservable, reschedulingObservable)
  .do(() => {
    if (keepWatching) {
      setTimeout(() => reschedulingSubject.next('forced-next'), 100);
    }
  })
  .subscribe(event => console.info(event));
```

That code produces the following stream:

```
event-0
forced-next
event-3
event-4
forced-next
forced-next
event-5
forced-next
forced-next
event-6
Source observable is complete. Stop watching please
forced-next
```

---

Pros of this code are:

- Does almost exactly what you asked in the question. (Saying *almost* because of  `setTimeout(() => reschedulingSubject.next('forced-next'), 100)`).
- Does not require custom operators.

Cons are:

- Pretty complex code for "such a simple problem".
- Uses `Subject` which is a last resort kind of a thing, IMO.

---

Again, you asked a very good question. Always interesting to deal with puzzles like this. Starring the question!

Comment: Initially, the server doesn't send me enough information so that I need to make additional query back to him. So If he sends me the update 1 million times, I will make 2 x 1 mil request back. It is so bad. Then I tried debounceTime. It is the right way to do but then my question came out. Thanks for your time even I haven't gotten back to your comment in the question. Your plunker looks very good, it is what I am looking for.

Comment: Yeah, I will accept the answer for sure but I am just testing it a bit more. Just a question, if I want to clear the timeout after event-6 passed, what do you think is the best way? Understand that all the event will come very randomly and it is difficult to fulfill.

Comment: @trungk18 yeah, do test the solution as you wish.  my laptop is off already cause it's late in my timezone. I'd wrap the `do` into a stop if-statement, which should be set from the sourceObservable on its completion

Comment: Just removed my comment because it didn't work :)) Sure, thank you again.

Comment: @trungk18 I updated my answer. See how keepWatching variable is used to control the termination of listening. Does this variant look better to you?

Comment: Yeah, It is what I am looking for. Thanks, @igor for your time spent.

Comment: @trungk18 NP. Glad to help, and enjoyed the puzzle. Hope, somebody posts an even cleaner answer.

Comment: 2 subscriptions, shared variables between observables... hard too read... I just don't like your solution. Check mine's @Igor, does the same and it is much cleaner. 
Note: your timeout doesn't make sense on 100 ms, put it in 0 ms will do same effect.

Comment: @LlorençPujolFerriol i don's see you solution ever terminating; and the fiddle has two subscriptions as well. It's more terse though, and frankly I somehow overlooked it yesterday.  Up voting

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko sure, it has 2 subscriptions, that can be 1 if merged, it is only for read purposes. Final is no needed to show how the fucntionallity has to work. Thanks. Your solution is exactly the same with timeout 0 ms, I posted mine only for trungk to match exactly with his code and for cleaner code.

Answer (score 1):

This is my take on it - if I understood the question correctly, which I'm not sure of... Nevertheless, code is below.

```
// this is just simulation of source of events - in the real world it is this.signalR.itemCreated
// values are such that they would be distinguishable from interval numbers.
// and yes, it is Igor's idea :)
const sourceObservable = Observable.create(observer => {
    setTimeout(() => observer.next(100), 0);
    setTimeout(() => observer.next(101), 1000);
    setTimeout(() => observer.next(102), 1100);
    setTimeout(() => observer.next(103), 1500);
    setTimeout(() => observer.next(104), 1700);
    setTimeout(() => observer.next(105), 2100);
    setTimeout(() => observer.next(106), 4200);
    setTimeout(() => observer.next(107), 5000);
    setTimeout(() => observer.next(108), 8000);
});

// debouncing too fast emits
const itemCreated = sourceObservable.debounceTime(300);

// starting timer after last emitted event
// again, in the real world interval should be 1 minute, this is just for illustrative purposes
const timeout = itemCreated.switchMap(() => Observable.interval(2000));

// then just merging those two
// debounceTime(300) - to suppress possible fast timer->source consequent events
// take(12) is just to limit example length, it is not needed in real application
itemCreated.merge(timeout).debounceTime(300).take(12).subscribe((val) => console.log(`${val}`));
```

This produces the following sequence:

```
100
// 101 skipped here by sourceObservable.debounceTime(300)
102
// 103 skipped here by sourceObservable.debounceTime(300)
104
105
// 0 from interval() skipped here by merge().debounceTime(300)
106
107
0
108
0
1
2
3
```

PS. And I agree with Igor - that's an interesting brainteaser, thanks for interesting question!

Comment: I was thinking in a pretty much same direction and had written a the very same code. This one is better than my answer in terms of simplicity -- no tricks of manual control over sequence creation via `Subject` is used. This code is worse than my answer in terms of correctness `.debounceTime(300)` in the last line may delay _any_ event **including the "forced" scheduled one**. This may or may not be a big deal for the OP. Good try, Alexander

Comment: @Igor - exactly. We don't know exact requirements, so, to me it sounds like that final delay is not a big deal for OP. Though it may easily be not true because ... (see starting sentence). :)

Comment: @Igor - actually, first `debounceTime()` can be safely skipped. Also, to me it does not make sense to care about 300ms delay when later we're waiting for 1 minute...

Comment: I would not assume whether those 300ms debounce on 1 minute are important or not -- we don't know the use case...

Comment: That's why we have to assume ***something***. :) Otherwise no solution could be found at all because present requirements can be interpreted too broadly.

Comment: My answer is based on _fewer_ of the avoidable assumptions. I don not find the problem definition too broad, it only missed one important detail originally.

Comment: Well, if OP need to wait for at least a minute after last call then your solution is incorrect at all. ;) But again - we don't know that... So, until OP arrives and clarify what they need we will continue our guessing...

Comment: `then your solution is incorrect at all` -- explain please? I hope you're not talking about the constant delays I selected _for demonstration purposes_.

Comment: throttleTime(60000) will not ensure 1 minute since last itemCreated event. So, let's assume (again, it's speculation - we don't know!) that requirement is to issue requests no frequently then 300 ms but wait for no more then 1 minute **if no items arrived** - your algorithm will work differently: it will ensure requests no less then once a minute regardless of when items are emitted. The point is - we can guess infinitely until OP clarifies what they really want. Until then there's no "better" or "worse" - it's "guessed correctly" or not. :)

Comment: my code does **not** use `throttleTime()` at all. ;) Making fewer guesses is better, IMO

Comment: I need more sleep... :(