# How to skip items of observables while processing using RxJS in combination with elapsing timer

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, rxjs, reactive-programming

I have a (time-consuming) calculation, something like that:

```js
async calculation(input: MyInputType): Promise<MyOutputType> {
   // fetch some infos from an HTTP endpoint
   // calculate result by combining received infos with input
   return result; // Promise which resolves after all calculation is complete
}
```

The input for the calculation comes from another component via an observable (`BehaviorSubject`) which emits items sometimes faster than they can be processed. The output is thus dependent on the observable and the fetched infos from the http endpoint, which can also change from time to time.

Important: **Only** the **last** calculation **result is relevant** for my application and must be available in a variable at any time.
My goal is to use RxJS and its reactive operators to setup an observable-chain with the following behavior:

- Items from the source `BehaviorSubject` emitted while a calculation is currently processing should be ignored (backpressuring to prevent DoS), but...
- When the current calculation is completed or a timeout occurs, a new calculation must be started directly for the most recent input item, if there is a new one.
- If no calculation has been started for at least 5 minutes, a new calculation has to be started, again with the most recent input item. (This is important to update the expiring http infos)

Does anyone have any idea how solve this problem?
(I'm using RxJS 5, TypeScript, Node.js, but reactive solutions in other languages are also welcome.)

Comment: I think this question is pretty darn close to what you're trying to achieve. https://stackoverflow.com/q/46785128/482868

Comment: What happens if a calculation takes longer than 5 minutes? Is a new calculation still started, and what happens to the old calculation if so?

Comment: Good question, but this should never happen because of the timeout I mentioned in the second bullet point. This timeout (of the calculation itself) is, of course, less than 5 minutes. The result can therefore be discarded in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

From where I'm standing, there are two separate questions. The first is how to repeat calculations on an item that has already been calculated if 5 minutes elapse. Let's start with filling spaces of >5 minutes with cloned repetitions of the last value. The cloning will be important later.

```
// inputs$: Observable<MyInputType>
const spacefilled_inputs$ = inputs$.switchMap(input => Observable.interval(5000).map(() => Object.assign({}, input)))
                                   .merge(input$);
```

The second question is trickier: how to trigger `calculation` when both the previous calculation (if there was one) completes, *and* when a new input is emitted from `spacefilled_inputs$`? Fair warning: RxJS doesn't do this very naturally. I'll lay down some code first and explain after:

```
const promise_subject = new Subject<Promise<MyOutputType>>();
const results$ = promise_subject.asObservable()
                                .flatMap(promise => Observable.fromPromise(promise));
Observable.combineLatest(spacefilled_inputs$, results$)
          .pairwise()
          .scan(([inputs_changed, results_changed], [prev_pair, next_pair]) => {
            // assumes that both MyInputType and MyOutputType are non-primitive objects
            inputs_changed = inputs_changed || prev_pair[0] !== next_pair[0];
            results_changed = results_changed || prev_pair[1] !== next_pair[1];

            if(inputs_changed && results_changed) {
                promise_subject.next(calculation(next_pair[1]));
                return [false, false];
            }
            return [inputs_changed, results_changed];
          }, [true, true]);
```

Foremost, we'll stream the calculation results through a subject, so that they can signal further calculations. The key here is [`pairwise`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/pairwise.html), which emits frames of the previous and incoming element so we can compare them. The body of `scan` compares and maintains state on if both the inputs and the results have changed.

Note the check for change uses strict equality for object references. If `MyOutputType` or `MyInputType` are primitives, this will incorrectly screen out duplicate values. You'll have to do something similar then with counters on the input and the result streams.

Comment: Many thanks for your response!

To the first part: I like the solution very well. I just wonder why the `Object.assign` is necessary. (My input objects can be quite large). Is it not sufficient to call mapTo?  
`inputs$.switchMap(input => Observable.interval(5000).mapTo(input)).merge(input$)`  

To the second part: I have to admit that I have not yet understood your code 100%. The solution seems relatively complicated to me. I'll report again when I have a better understanding of your code. Easier solutions for part 2 are welcome.

Comment: @Niehno Without cloning, the calculation won't be retried every 5 minutes if `scan` detects changes as it does above, because it'll be getting the same object. I agree, it's not the most performant solution, so you can tie a counter to both streams, unfortunately at the expense of further complicating part 2.